# perl: finding the region with the greatest width from a list

Tags: perl

I have a table having the following structure

```
gene    transcript    exon    length
A       NM_1          1       10
A       NM_1          2       5
A       NM_1          3       20
A       NM_2          1       10
A       NM_2          2       5
A       NM_2          3       50
B       NM_5          1       10
...     ...           ...     ...
```

So basically, the table consists of a column with all human genes. The second column contains the transcript name. The same gene can have multiple transcripts. The third column contains an exon number. Every gene consists of multiple exons. The fourth column contains the length of each exon.

Now I want to create a new table looking like this:

```
 gene   transcript    length
 A      NM_2          65
 B      NM_5          10
 ...    ...           ...
```

So what I basically want to do is find the longest transcript for each gene.
This means that when there are multiple transcripts (column transcript) for each gene (column gene), I need to make the sum of the values in the length column for all the exons of the transcript of that gene.

So in the example there are two transcripts for gene A: NM_1 and NM_2. Each has three exons. The sum of these three values for NM_1 = 10+5+20 = 35, for NM_2 it's 10+5+50 = 65. So for gene A, NM_2 is the longest transcript, so I want to put this in the new table. For gene B there is only 1 transcript, with one exon of length 10. So in the new table, I just want the length of this transcript reported.

I've worked with hashes before, so I thought of storing 'gene' and 'transcript' as two different keys:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $test,'<',"test.txt") || die ("Could not open file $!");
open(my $output, '+>', "output.txt") || die ("Can't write new file: $!");

# skip the header of $test # I know how to do this

my %hash = ();
while(<$test>){
    chomp;
    my @cols = split(/\t/);
    my $keyfield = $cols[0]; #gene name
    my $keyfield2 = $cols[1]; # transcript name
    push @{ $hash{$keyfield} }, $keyfield2;
```

...

Comment: As a hint - you'll get better response if you show some attempt to solve the problem yourself. I would suggest starting by looking at hashes.

Comment: I've worked with hashes before, but not as complex as this. Would my suggestion above work?

Comment: Is your output `length` field the sum of the lengths? It looks like it.

Comment: yes indeed, the sum of the lengths

Comment: What happens if a gene has multiple transcripts with the same maximum length?

Comment: @Borodin it actually doesn't matter then which transcript it reports. Let's say the first one it encounters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you're trying to do, I'd be thinking something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %genes;

my $header_line = <DATA>;

#read the data
while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $gene, $transcript, $exon, $length ) = split;
    $genes{$gene}{$transcript} += $length;
}

print join( "\t", "gene", "transcript", "length_sum" ), "\n";

foreach my $gene ( keys %genes ) {
    #sort by length_sum, and 'pop' the top of the list. 
    my ($longest_transcript) =
        ( sort { $genes{$gene}{$b} <=> $genes{$gene}{$a} or $a cmp $b }
            keys %{ $genes{$gene} } );
    print join( "\t",
        $gene, $longest_transcript, $genes{$gene}{$longest_transcript} ),
        "\n";
}


__DATA__ 
gene    transcript    exon    length
A       NM_1          1       10
A       NM_1          2       5
A       NM_1          3       20
A       NM_2          1       10
A       NM_2          2       5
A       NM_2          3       50
B       NM_5          1       10
```

**output**

```
gene    transcript  length_sum
B   NM_5    10
A   NM_2    65
```

Comment: what do you mean with: my $header_line = <DATA>; Why is it necessary and why call it header_line?

Comment: That reads the first line from the `__DATA__` block - which is the row `gene transcript exon length` - which we don't need, and don't want to process.

Comment: and what is happening here in the case that two transcripts of one gene have the same length?

Comment: It'll be whatever order they're extracted from the hash - so random. If you want it defined, then you'll need to extend the `sort` sub. For example: `sort { $genes{$gene}{$b} <=> $genes{$gene}{$a} or $b cmp $a }`

Comment: Code edited. `$b cmp $a` will give you the _last_ alphanumeric 'NM_n' sorted. `$a cmp $b` will give you the _first_ transcript alphanumerically.

Answer (score 0):

This is made much less untidy using the `nmax_by` (numeric maximum by) function from [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy). This program accumulates the total length in a hash and then picks out the longest transcript for each gene using `nmax_by`.

I presume you're able to open the input file on `$fh` instead of using the `DATA` handle? Or you could pass the path to the input file on the command line and just use `<>` instead of `<$fh>`without explicitly opening anything.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::UtilsBy qw/ nmax_by /;

my $fh = \*DATA;

<$fh>; # Drop header line

my %genes;

while ( <$fh> ) {
  my ($gene, $trans, $exon, $len) = split;
  $genes{$gene}{$trans} += $len;
}

my $fmt = "%-7s%-14s%-s\n";
printf $fmt, qw/ gene transcript length /;
for my $gene ( sort keys %genes ) {
  my $trans = nmax_by { $genes{$gene}{$_} } keys %{ $genes{$gene} };
  printf ' '.$fmt, $gene, $trans, $genes{$gene}{$trans};
}


__DATA__
gene    transcript    exon    length
A       NM_1          1       10
A       NM_1          2       5
A       NM_1          3       20
A       NM_2          1       10
A       NM_2          2       5
A       NM_2          3       50
B       NM_5          1       10
```

**output**

```
gene   transcript    length
 A      NM_2          65
 B      NM_5          10
```

---

**Update**

Here's a much shortened version of `nmax_by` that will work for you to test. You can add this at the top of the program, or if you'd rather put it at the end then you need to pre-declare it with `sub nmax_by(&@);` at the top because it has a prototype

```
sub nmax_by(&@) {
   my $code = shift;
   my ($max, $maxval);
   for ( @_ ) {
     my $val = $code->($_);
     ($max, $maxval) = ($_, $val) unless defined $maxval and $maxval >= $val;
   }
   $max;
}
```

Comment: not able to test this now since I'm working on a server where I cannot install perl modules. But will definitely test this.